# Maximum Number of Occurrences of Any Item in Counter object / list

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, counter

I have a grid filled with different colors (represented by differing integers). I would like to quickly (in one line and least amount of processing time) count the number of occurrences of all the colors and return the highest number of occurrences. Also, I want to ignore zeroes.

Here is my solution (can you think of a better one?):

```
grid = [[0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0], [0, 30, 30, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 30, 0, 0, 33, 33, 0, 0, 50, 0, 50, 0, 0], [0, 30, 0, 0, 33, 33, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 88, 88, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
rows,cols=len(grid),len(grid[0])
ctrSum=Counter()
for row in grid:
    ctrSum += Counter(row)
ctrSum -= Counter({0:(rows*cols)}) # subtract out a ridiculous amount of zeroes to eliminate them all from the counter
return max(ctrSum.values())
```

Comment: If you wanna ignore 0s, why are you counting them in the first place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Pranav types faster than me, here is another potential answer to your problem:

```py
ans = max(Counter(x for row in grid for x in row if x!=0).values())
```

I thought about irregular nested lists and this is what can do it:

```py
unfurl=lambda x: sum(map(unfurl,x),[]) if isinstance(x,list) or isinstance(x, tuple) else [x]
ans = max(Counter(unfurl(grid)).values())
```

Comment: So, any n-dimensional array can be flattened using ```x for item_nminus1 in narray for item_nminus2 in item_nminus1 ... for x in item_nis2```. That's nice.

Comment: Yeah, @bittahProfessional we can also handle it dynamically, just edited for the same!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding the counts for each row to the counter in a loop, you can flatten the list-of-lists *while creating the counter!*

```
ctr = Counter(x for row in grid for x in row)
# Counter({0: 79, 5: 1, 10: 4, 30: 4, 33: 5, 50: 6, 88: 5})
```

Then, delete the `0` key, and find the max:

```
del ctr[0]
max_key, max_count = max(ctr.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]) # 50, 6
```

Counting the zeros and deleting the key later is not significantly faster or slower than not counting them at all (On my computer, `timeit` returned similar times for both approaches)

```
grid = [[0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0], [0, 30, 30, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 30, 0, 0, 33, 33, 0, 0, 50, 0, 50, 0, 0], [0, 30, 0, 0, 33, 33, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 88, 88, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

def m1(grid):
    rows,cols=len(grid),len(grid[0])
    ctrSum=Counter()
    for row in grid:
        ctrSum += Counter(row)
    ctrSum -= Counter({0:(rows*cols)}) # subtract out a ridiculous amount of zeroes to eliminate them all from the counter
    return max(ctrSum.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

def m2(grid):
    ctr = Counter(x for row in grid for x in row)
    del ctr[0]
    return max(ctr.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])

def m3(grid):
    ctr = Counter(x for row in grid for x in row if x)
    return max(ctr.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])

def m3_oneline(grid):
    return max(Counter(x for row in grid for x in row if x).items(), key=lambda x: x[1])


t1 = timeit.timeit('func(grid)', setup='from __main__ import grid, m1 as func', number=10000)
t2 = timeit.timeit('func(grid)', setup='from __main__ import grid, m2 as func', number=10000)
t3 = timeit.timeit('func(grid)', setup='from __main__ import grid, m3 as func', number=10000)
t3_oneline = timeit.timeit('func(grid)', setup='from __main__ import grid, m3_oneline as func', number=10000)

print(t2/t1, t3/t1, t3_oneline/t1)
0.3436699657289107 0.3483052483876959 0.3614440352763763
```

- `m1` (predictably) takes the longest time since you're creating all those counters only to add their values together.
- `m2` and `m3` take ~34% of the time taken by `m1`. There is not a significant difference in runtime between counting zeros and not counting zeros, since you need to check if it is a zero anyway in order to decide not to count it.
- `m3_oneline` is *ever so slightly* slower than `m2` and `m3` (i.e. a one-liner is not necessarily more efficient.)

Comment: Yeah, one liners certainly don't guarantee speed. Since it was comparable to optimized multi-liner & asker specifically requested for a pretty to look at one-liner, I added it.

Comment: Hmm, on tio.run I consistently get ~0.33 ~0.21 ~0.21. With their "Python 3.8 (pre-release)". What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line, using `reduce()` to build a Counter that contains the frequencies for the elements across all the rows, then passing a `key` to `max()` that eliminates 0 from consideration when finding the most frequent element:

```py
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
import math

result = max(reduce(lambda x, y: x + Counter(y), grid, Counter()).items(),
     key=lambda x: x[1] if x[0] else -math.inf)
print(result)
```

You can also add all the Counters together using `sum()`:

```py
result = max(sum(map(Counter, grid), Counter()).items(),
     key=lambda x: x[1] if x[0] else -math.inf)
print(result)
```

With the above grid, both of these print:

```py
(50, 6)
```